# find string in e.g. a txt file from dataframe column1 and replace it with string from dataframe column2

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace string in python from a txt file in the following way:

The words from a pandas dataframe in column1 should be searched for in the txt file and be replaced by the words in the same row from column 2.

Importing the txt file and dataframe is no problem.

For example:

original text:

> *This is the **first** sentence I want to change. This is the **alpha** sentence I want to change.*

dataframe:

```
    column1 column2
0   first   last
1   alpha   beta
```

desired result:

> *This is the **last** sentence I want to change. This is the **beta** sentence I want to change.*

I thought of a dict with using column1 as keys and column2 as values, but I could't get it to work. Half a day searching brought me to no result, all search results related to replace values in dataframes, which is not my problem here.

Comment: What part are you struggling with, specifically? Can you provide some more context for this? Why are the strings in a DataFrame in the first place?

Comment: jezrael did help me out with his code, it worked. the dataframe is a dictionary itself, imported from an external file. it should be updatable without changing any code. I am still not sure, how these of his lines work exactly: ```pat = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(d.keys()) + r')\b')
out = pat.sub(lambda x: d[x.group()], s)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionary from both columns and then replace with regex `re.sub`:

```
import re

d = df.set_index('column1')['column2'].to_dict()
print (d)
{'first': 'last', 'alpha': 'beta'}

s = 'This is the first sentence I want to change. This is the alpha sentence I want to change.'

pat = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(d.keys()) + r')\b')
out = pat.sub(lambda x: d[x.group()], s)
print (out)
This is the last sentence I want to change. This is the beta sentence I want to change.
```

If always one word replacement is possible also use:

```
for key in d:
    s = s.replace(key, d[key])
print (s)
This is the last sentence I want to change. This is the beta sentence I want to change.
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast! It works! Awesome, thank you very much!

Could you explain what these lines do exaclty? I want to understand all of the code, and not just use it:

pat = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(d.keys()) + r')\b')
out = pat.sub(lambda x: d[x.group()], s)